# Why does it give an error when typing "done"?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

this is my problem
Can you help me?
Thanks

Write a program that asks the user to repeatedly ask for a number until the word "done" is typed, then by entering "done" the three values ​​of "sum of numbers", "number of numeric inputs", "average of numbers". Print.
Your application should use try and except when the user enters a non-numeric input, show him the "Invalid input" error message and go to the number request again.
Like the following example:

```
Enter a number: 4                                                                                 
‌Enter a number: 5                                                                                      
Enter a number: bad data                                                                              
Invalid input                                                                                                           
Enter a number: 7                                                                                         
Enter a number: done                                                                                         
16                                                                                                                   
3                                   
5.333333333333333
```

I type the code below

```
while True :
    try: 
        number = input ('Enter number: ')
        n = int (number)
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
    if n == 'done' :
        break
x = None
y = None
for Total in [n] :
    x = x + n
    print (x)
for num in [n] :
    y = y + 1
    print (y)
for Average in [n] :
    x = x + n
    y = y + 1
    aver = x / y
    print ( aver)
```

And when I type "done" it displays a "Invalid input" warning

```
Enter number: 2
Enter number: 3
Enter number: 4
Enter number: done
Invalid input
Enter number:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you type `'done'`, `number` becomes equal to the string `'done'`
2. `n = int (number)` is then the same as `n = int ('done')`, which raises an exception, because `'done'` can't be parsed as a base-10 integer

   1. Note that since the call `int ('done')` raised an error, the value of `n` *doesn't change*
3. So you get to the `except` clause and `print('Invalid input')`
4. Since the value of `n` remained the same, `n == 'done'` is `False`
5. Thus, the loop continues

You can fix it by moving the check inside the `except` clause:

```
while True:
    try: 
        number = input ('Enter number: ')
        n = int (number)
    except:
        if number == 'done':
            break
        print('Invalid input')
```

---

Also note that this code:

```
for Total in [n] :
    ...
```

...will create a list with *one* element `[n]` and iterate over this list *once*, because there's only one element. So, it won't really compute any sum.

---

Furthermore, this code will attempt to add a number to `None`:

```
x = None
y = None
for Total in [n] :
    x = x + n
    print (x)
```

On the first iteration, `x = x + n` will evaluate to `x = None + <integer>`, which is invalid since `None` can't be added to anything.

---

Moreover, judging by your input, you want to input *multiple* numbers, however the first `while` loop will overwrite the variable `n` with a *new* number on each iteration, so all previous numbers will be lost.

You should *accumulate* these numbers somewhere:

```
numbers = []
while True:
    try: 
        number = input ('Enter number: ')
        n = int (number)
    except:
        if number == 'done':
            break
        print('Invalid input')
    else:
        # There was no exception
        numbers.append(n)
```

Comment: You may as well check if `number == 'done'` *before* the `try` statement. And the only exception for which `Invalid input` will make sense is the `ValueError` that `int` raises; catch that specifically, rather than catching any exception whatsoever.

Comment: Thak you help me